# Doxygen include css to htmlinclude file

Tags: html, css, include, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document some C++ code, I have managed to successfully include a HTML file with `@htmlinclude`, however in the HTML file I am putting `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` to include a CSS file and in the console, it appears as file not found. Am I missing something here or is it not possible to include CSS files in Doxygen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen has configuration settings for stylesheets:

- HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  (http://doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_stylesheet)

  > The HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET tag can be used to specify additional user-defined cascading style sheets that are included after the standard style sheets created by doxygen. Using this option one can overrule certain style aspects. This is preferred over using HTML_STYLESHEET since it does not replace the standard style sheet and is therefore more robust against future updates. Doxygen will copy the style sheet files to the output directory.

I don't think you might need the `HTML_EXTRA_FILES` together with  `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`(and otherwise it doesn't hurt to know about the possibility):

- HTML_EXTRA_FILES (http://doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_files)

  > The HTML_EXTRA_FILES tag can be used to specify one or more extra images or other source files which should be copied to the HTML output directory. Note that these files will be copied to the base HTML output directory.

Comment: Thanks again Albert